# queueing network and mean value analysis

Tags: java, queueing

1) i am trying to code the calculation of "residence time" for multi class jobs using "approximate MVA"(mean value analysis).

2) i have a program with "Exact MVA". i am using 2 classes and 2 stations. the problem is that the throughput for each class is almost half what we get when calculating using single class MVa.
is this OK or the program is giving wrong output?

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to try to multi-thread an application but find the performance is no better or worse.  The common causes are;

- Using a resource which is already at its limit and is single threaded e.g. one CPU, one disk, one network, one lock or your CPU to memory bandwidth is reached.
- The overhead exceeds the benefit. esp for short lived tasks.